# About basic ideas of '4+1' view model in software artechiture

Tags: architecture, software

I'm new in software engineering and I recently read Philippe Kruchten's famous paper 'Architectural Blueprints—The “4+1” View Model of Software Architecture'.

He defined 4+1 views includeing **Logical View**, **Process View**, **Development view** the **Physical view**, and use-case.

But I also find some people call them **Design View**, **Implementation View**, **Interaction View** and the  **Deployment View**.

What's the difference between them? Who change this? I'm feeling confused. Though there maybe little differences as they're the same thing but only in different names, I just wanna know why this change happen? Thx

Comment: There are a LOT of different takes on similar concepts in computer science. You'll drive yourself nuts if you try and treat them like laws of physics. Just use the mental models that are useful to you and don't sweat too much about divergent description

Comment: Take the word "view", add any noun or adjective in front, and someone has used that term, most of the time. I agree with Paul.

Answer (score 2):

You read a book about Software Engineering. Congratulations. You've discovered that it has it's own vocabulary that isn't universal. Do you want your money back?

Read more books and you'll find this happening, a lot. Come on our field is less than 100 years old. Math is much older and [still has this problem](https://tauday.com/tau-manifesto). There are at least as many ways to skin a cat as there are cats.

The important thing is if reading his book gave you a good way to think about how to solve your problems. If you manage to find someone who read the same book you now have a common language to use as a short hand to communicate these ideas. If not then fall back to using English.

The Gang of four patterns book probably came closest to giving us a new vocabulary to communicate complex ideas quickly. However I find I'm lucky if 50% of the people in a coding shop even heard of the book. And it has dozens of spin off books.

Maybe join a book club?